# Node.js: Unit testing, Expect error message when function requires specific value

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing, i was just doing random test for practice using `mocha.js` and `expect`

- [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect)
- [mocha.js](https://mochajs.org)

I just have a problem on making the unit testing to expect a specific error when it's calling a function with wrong values

Function:

```
module.exports.parseOptions = function(opts){
    if(utils.isFalsy(opts)){
        throw new Error("Options is undefined");
    }

    else if(!utils.isObject(opts)){
        throw new Error("Options parameter must be an object");
    }

    else{
        // Path is mandatory for this package, throw error if undefined
        if(!opts.path){
            throw new Error("Path for static files is undefined");
        }
        .......
    }
}
```

Unit test file:

```
var expect = require("expect");
var helper = require("./../lib/helper.js");

describe("helper functions", function(){
    it("should parse options", function(){
        //This process works fine
        expect(function(){
            helper.parseOptions();
        }).toThrow("Options is undefined");

        //This process fails for some reason
        expect(function(){
            helper.parseOptions([]);
        }).toThrow("Options parameter must be an object");
    });
})
```

What terminal shows:

```
helper functions
1) should parse options


0 passing (9ms)
1 failing

1) helper functions should parse options:
 Error: Expected [Function] to throw 'Options parameter must be an object'
  at assert (node_modules/expect/lib/assert.js:29:9)
  at Expectation.toThrow (node_modules/expect/lib/Expectation.js:104:28)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/test-driven-development.js:12:6)
```

I am struggling to understand how it really works, i would like to make unit testing to validate all kind of errors as well with expected values, if there is any other tool more useful, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason why the test is failing, looks like the parameter sent to the function is validating if it's falsy, meaning that `[]` value is falsy and so the function throws the error that the value is undefined

i had to change from:

```
module.exports.parseOptions = function(opts){
    if(utils.isFalsy(opts)){
        throw new Error("Options is undefined");
    }
        .......
}
```

to:

```
module.exports.parseOptions = function(opts){
    if(typeof opts == "undefined"){
        throw new Error("Options is undefined");
    }
        .......
}
```